# How to remove the double scroll?

Tags: html, css

I want to make facebook-style image viewer. It was ok when I had only image in the viewer and height of it wasn't bigger than 100%. But when I added description to images it become bigger, so that it took to scroll the viewer. After adding scroller to viewer it becomes two scrollers.

I looked to facebook, only viewer scrolling in there, body (under layer) are fixed. How to get this behavior?

### css of viewer container

```
#gallary-container {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    color: white;
}
```

### *edit:*

Actually question, how to disable scroller on body of page leave it only on viewer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was easy! I created class

```
.htmlfixed{
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
}
```

And appointed it to html tag in js.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to set

```
overflow:hidden;
```

on the box that gets the scrollbars

Comment: I know it, but height of my viewer bigger then 100% and it need to be scrolled. Second scroller is on body of the page and I need to disable it, and don't know how.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
<style>
  html {
    overflow-y: hidden;
  }
</style>
```